# Problema al eliminar elemento en array con mongodb y golang

Tags: array, mongodb, go

Estoy trabajando en mongodb y golang, pero no encuentro forma de eliminar un elemento del array "like"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa60f12fb2c4b99280f10b8"),
    "userid" : "5f93de9ad43f940b8ea9ff33",
    "mensaje" : "Like de prueba",
    "fecha" : ISODate("2020-11-07T03:05:54.106Z"),
    "like" : [ 
        "5f93de9ad43f940b8ea9ff33", 
        "5f93e041d43f940b8ea9ff34", 
        "5efc538ea235f8e21cdf4de6", 
        "5fa11e11a5968582ea7f3408", 
        "5f8e41d626e3cc7332c5479a"
    ]
}
```

este es mi codigo

package bd

```
import (
    "context"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

/*RemuevoLike graba la relación en la BD */
func RemuevoLike(TweetID string, IDUsuario string) (bool, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    objID, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(TweetID)

    db := MongoCN.Database("twitter")
    col := db.Collection("tweet")

    update := bson.M{
        "$pull ": bson.M{
            "like": IDUsuario,
        },
    }
    _, err := col.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": objID}, update)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

pero la respuesta me genera un

Ocurrió un error al intentar insertar el like multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{Unknown modifier: $pull . Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array}]}, {}]

vi que ya el operador $pull esta obsoleto, pero no encuentro nada actual o como implementarlo en golang

Answer (score 0):

ya lo pude resolver, por si alguno en algun momento le interesa

```
pullQuery := bson.M{"like": IDUsuario}
    _, err := col.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": objID}, bson.M{"$pull": pullQuery})
```